Length of a line drawn from arbitrary point on circle dividing axis
I'm trying to get an expression for the length of "r" drawn from point P to an arbitrary point M on the circle of radius R (see attached drawing).  Point P is always on the dividing axis of the circle.  I saw in a paper where the answer seems to be
$$r(\beta, b) = b\cos\beta + (1-b^2\sin^2\beta)^{1/2}$$
I'm not sure if this answer assumes a unit circle. So, if I define x,y as from the origin, O, then
$$r^2 = (x+b)^2+y^2$$
and
$$y = r\sin\beta$$
$$x+b = r\cos\beta$$
But this isn't getting me anywhere in terms of getting the first equation shown above (I'd like to include the radius, R, if necessary.)


What is “the dividing axis of the circle”?

Sorry, I couldn't remember what it is called.  On an ellipse it would be the major axis, so maybe it's just called axis.  At any rate it includes the center, O, and I guess it is essentially the x axis.

Yes, the paper's formula is assuming the circle radius is $1$. To get it, we can use your expressions for $x$ and $y$, plus the formula for a circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin. However, as you're also asking about the equivalent formula for a circle of radius $R$, I'll show the more general case here.
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x^2 + y^2 & = R^2 \\
(r\cos\beta - b)^2 + (r\sin\beta)^2 & = R^2 \\
r^2\cos^2\beta - 2br\cos\beta + b^2 + r^2\sin^2\beta & = R^2 \\
r^2(\cos^2\beta + \sin^2\beta) - (2b\cos\beta)r + b^2 & = R^2 \\
r^2 - (2b\cos\beta)r + b^2 - R^2 & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Note we can also more directly derive this same equation using the law of cosines with $\triangle POM$ to get
$$R^2 = b^2 + r^2 - 2br\cos\theta \;\;\to\;\; r^2 - (2b\cos\beta)r + b^2 - R^2 = 0$$
In either case, this is a quadratic equation in $r$, so using the quadratic formula, plus noting that $b \le R$ (so $- 4(b^2 - R^2) \ge 0$) and $r \gt 0$, we have
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
r(\beta, b) & = \frac{2b\cos\beta \pm \sqrt{(2b\cos\beta)^2 - 4(b^2 - R^2)}}{2} \\
& = b\cos\beta + \sqrt{b^2\cos^2\beta - b^2 + R^2} \\
& = b\cos\beta + \sqrt{R^2 + b^2(\cos^2\beta - 1)} \\
& = b\cos\beta + \sqrt{R^2 - b^2\sin^2\beta}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
